# mongodb descending ascending index

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

I'm learning about mongodb index and I would like to ask a question. I read the documentation about mongodb index. But I don't undertand a thing.

I have created a

> index price(-1)

If I use a

> sort price(1)

Does this sort use the index?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. `MongoDB` can scan an index from both directions, so it doesn't really matter what order your index is in. It only matters when you have a compound index (with multiple fields), where you can still start an index scan from both sides on the first field, but the next ones are fixed by the order you give them.

> Nevertheless, MongoDB may also traverse the index in either directions. As a result, for single-field indexes, ascending and descending indexes are interchangeable. This is not the case for compound indexes: in compound indexes, the direction of the sort order can have a greater impact on the results.

From the [`MongoDB` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/#ordering-of-indexes).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 100})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 110})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 120})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 130})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 140})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.save({price: 150})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.encureIndex({price:-1})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.find().sort({price:1}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor price_-1 reverse",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 6,
"nscannedObjects" : 6,
"nscanned" : 6,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 6,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 18,
"indexBounds" : {
    "price" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "localhost:27017"
}
rs0:PRIMARY> db.bill.find().sort({price:-1}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor price_-1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 6,
"nscannedObjects" : 6,
"nscanned" : 6,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 6,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 0,
"indexBounds" : {
    "price" : [
        [
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "localhost:27017"
}
```

Note cursors are: "BtreeCursor price_-1 reverse", and "BtreeCursor price_-1". Mongodb will use the "reverse index" automatically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, its a good question to have when studying indexes for the first time.
To answer your question, its basically developer's duty to use indexes such that it increases query performance. In your case, using indexes that are resulting in performance degradation, should not be used. Know your query pattern, before applying indexes and apply indexes as needed.

There is a also inbuilt Query-optimizer in MongoDB which is empirical. Now how this works is, to test query plans, it tries several in parallel, and records the plan which finishes fastest. If plans performance change overtime e.g as data changes, DB will re-optimize (i.e retry all the possible plans).

You can also optimize query yourself. To test your query plan used, you can use explain() after your query, like

```
   db.collection.find({}).sort({price:1}).explain()
```

results in---

```
 {
   "cursor": "BtreeCursor x_1",
   ...
   "nscanned": 100
   ....

 }
```

Query plan that use indexes have cursor type BtreeCursor. And if query plan doesn't use the indexes, cursor type is BasicCursor.

Link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/

Comment: You do not need to `hint()` for the query planner to walk an index in reverse (if this is applicable), and you can only hint with an existing index spec or name. If you only have an index on `{price:1}` then a hint on `{price:-1}` should fail with a "bad hint" exception. In general you should use `hint()` *very* sparingly. Forcing a specific index often decreases performance; it would be better to understand why an expected index is not being used for a given query shape.